# Struct ou Classes?

Tags: c++, classes, desempenho, struct, c++-builder

Fiz o código usando estrutura, queria saber se com classes seria mais eficiente. Estou fazendo no C++ Builder. A ideia do código e a seguinte: criar uma lista de problemas, onde durante a execução do código sera acrescentados e retirados inúmeros problemas (do tipo `struct` ou `class`)

```
struct {
 TList *cidadesvisitadas; // lista iniciada com uma cidade ,vou acrescentando ate 30 cidades
 float  distancia;
 TList *cidadescanditadas; // lista iniciada com 29 cidades , que no decorrer  do codigo vai sendo retirada uma a uma e adicionada na lista de cidades visitadas
};
```

Na lista de problemas, será adicionado um problema inicial (não resolvido), e depois retirado esse problema se transforma em três novos problemas (não resolvido) que são adicionados novamente a lista de problemas, depois retiro um problema novamente da lista de problemas e se transforma em outros três problemas e assim por diante. A lista no final da execução ficar vazia (acrescenta e retira, quando o problema estiver resolvido ele não volta para a lista). Os problemas já estanciados dinamicamente (serão milhões de problemas)
se eu trocar a `struct` (Problema) por `class` (Problema), o código fica mais correto?

Comment: Dê uma olha no [tour], você pode votar em tudo no site que achar que é um bom conteúdo, além de aceitar uma resposta em perguntas suas, como já sabe fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C++ estruturas e classes são virtualmente a mesma coisa (classes possuem membros privados por padrão), então não faz diferença, nenhuma, nem de desempenho.

Como vai montar e usar o código faz diferença. É comum as pessoas deixarem `struct` para estruturas simples, sem métodos, ou seja, POD (Plain Old Data), e classes quando são objetos mais completos. Tem quem prefira usar `struct` quando o tipo será mais usado como valor e `class` para objetos que costumarão ser usados como referência, mas nem sempre isso funciona tão preto no branco.

Claro que classes não podem ser usadas com C. Dependendo de como use `struct` também não pode.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

Primeiramente, **struct não é a mesma coisa que uma classe** como muitos te responderam, apesar de ambas serem extremamente parecidas, tanto em questão de sintaxe (escrita no próprio código) quanto no resultado exibido.

- Classe: **Uma classe é uma estrutura** que comporta **atributos** e **métodos**. Para acessar essas características, é necessário a criação de um objeto. Você pode acessar as informações de uma classe após a criação do objeto através da nomenclatura `objeto->atributo;` ou `objeto->funcao();`

**Observação:** Uma classe pode se comunicar com a outra assim como um objeto pode se comunicar com outro.

- Struct: **Uma struct é uma estrutura**, assim como uma classe, mas que comporta **somente atributos**. Não há como criar métodos. Além disso, para acessar as características de uma estrutura é utilizado um **mecanismo de acesso**, o que é completamente diferente de um objeto. Para acessar as informações de uma struct você pode utilizar a nomenclatura `acesso.atributo;`

**Observação:** Uma struct não pode se comunicar diretamente com uma outra struct assim como um mecanismo de acesso não pode se comunicar com outro.

Em síntese, uma classe é uma estrutura extremamente mais elaborada, com interações e comunicações diretas com a funcionalidade do seu programa. Uma struct é somente uma estrutura estética, que serve para acoplar dados similares em somente um lugar, apesar de também ser funcional ao poder criar vários mecanismos de acesso e, portanto, acessar vários atributos.

A sua pergunta não é a diferença entre as duas, mas através dessas informações você pode deduzir, ao desenvolver o seu projeto, qual é a melhor opção. Pelo que eu consegui entender, class seria uma melhor opção, uma vez que você poderá elaborar a solução dos problemas exibidos através de métodos induzidos na própria classe.

Comment: Isso é simplesmente falso. `struct` é uma classe com membros públicos por padrão. Só isso. Em C, `struct`s realmente só possuem atributos, mas estamos falando de C++.